# How to make possible to install Samsung Kies?

Tags: software-recommendation, android, development, samsung

I am not sure where this question is set to proper place or not. If not then please guide me to that place.

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII, and doing Android development.

A couple of days before I was using Windows OS, but now I am using Ubuntu.

In Windows I am able to debug my Android app into Galaxy SII with the help of Samsung Kies, but I am not able to do this in Ubuntu.

So what is the alternate of it for Ubuntu. I have googled many times but still not get Kies that support for Ubuntu.

Comment: If you try VirtualBox be careful flashing any updates or ROMs, I bricked mine and had to return it for a warranty exchange. Consider dual-booting for proprietary hardware like that.

Comment: Oracle VM virtual box with tiny xp works fine for tomtom and other apps that don't like Linux or Wine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if I'm reading this right, you simply want to debug your app on your Android device. If that is correct, then all you would really need is the Android SDK and set up ADB or "Android Debug Bridge". Its not terribly difficult, but may take some work to get usb working correctly. You will also need to go to Settings>Applications>Debugging>Enable USB Debugging. If using Eclipse to do the application development, there are several tools that will automate sending the test version of the app to your phone.

For a more in depth answer, look at the Android Developer Site here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Also, it appears that there is no solution for kies on linux. I don't know anything about kies, but the standard Android app development method should work just fine and there's plenty of documentation at the developer site.

Comment: :Yes You are right. I know everything about how to develope andorid appa and what are the thing need for it. But i want to run the samsung kies in to ubuntu as because only samsung kies allows to debug some of the Samsung device like galaxy sII to debug android app. Hope you got my point.

Comment: I suppose you could try running the Windows version in Wine, but I'm not sure if that would be successful. It would require a bit of tinkering most likely to get it working.

Comment: ok will try of it.

Answer (score 5):

I have a Galaxy (great phone by the way) but sadly have to confirm that you won't get Samsung Kies working in Wine. If you succeed in getting Kies installed, you are unlikely to establish proper contact with the phone. This is I believe due to limited usb support in wine. (this is the reason tomtom home won't run in wine - it will install perfectly, but it can't talk to the device)

My attempts to get it working in a Win XP virtual machine running in virtualbox also failed - invariably the virtual XP installation froze and had to be forcefully shut down.

Drag and drop in native (k)ubuntu works fine (but I suppose you already know that) but in my experience Kies needs a full-blown windows.

If you do succeed in getting it running in 'buntu I and no doubt many others will be very keen to hear.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need Kies or a driver to use ADB and the sdk on Linux. 
First go to the android developer web site and install the SDK and Eclipse. I expect as you are developing on Windows already you'll work this bit out following their instructions.

In Linux a usb driver can be in user space, that is built right into the program. The coder uses the libusb API for this. But there is a little more, it will not work out of the box.

When a USB device is inserted into you PC the service udev is used to arbitrate how and where the 'device' is mounted. As your phone, when in debug mode, is unknown to the system it will only create the usb file node, which libusb uses to talk to it. Everything is a file in Linux. The problem is that this node is only accessible by the root account. You need to tell udev to allow a program, ADB in this case, talk to it with a normal user account.

To do this you create a file in /etc/udev/rules.d/

I have one called 99-my.rules

In this file, for your S2, add the single line
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8",ATTR{idProduct}="685e", OWNER="YOUR USERNAME", GROUP="YOUR USERNAME"

Where YOUR USERNAME is, put your username.

You'll have to be the root account to do this, in ubuntu use sudo in front of the command your are calling. EG sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/99-my.rules

Now reboot or run sudo service udev restart

Plug phone in and test with adb devices. Should show the phone ID.

Ubuntu is perfect for Android development, I use it at work all the time. Whilst the windows guys are trying to find drivers for a new device being tested I just do lsusb get the idVendor and idProduct values, add a new line in udev and restart the service and i'm up and running. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can run Kies on Ubuntu, I had it on my netbook for about two months before I changed to Mint. It works perfectly on Ubuntu, sadly though it does not on Mint, Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

You will need Wine to downdload it. It will thow up an error message near the end but it will still work fine.